# Duda con ArrayLists en Java

Tags: java, arraylist

mi duda es la siguiente:

¿Se puede volcar el contenido que hay en un ArrayList hasta el momento en un ArrayList> y luego el primero reiniciarlo para meter otra serie de datos y volcarlo en otra posición del segundo?

Explico la pregunta.

Estoy haciendo un programa que almacena una serie de palabras dependiendo del idioma que se le indique y debe ser con ArrayList de ArrayList, por lo cual, yo leo de un fichero externo 50 palabras, de las cuales las 25 primeras son del idioma 1 y las 25 segundas del idioma 2; entonces, me gustaría poder leer las primeras 25 y volcarlas a la primera posición del ArrayList de ArrayList y luego leer las siguientes 25 y volcarlas a la 2ª posición.

El problema que tengo es que cuando hago el primer volcado, todo va bien, pero al hacer el segundo volcado, como el arraylist que almacena las palabras tiene ya 50 posiciones, el que almacena los arraylist, ya tiene dos posiciones de 50 palabras cada uno.

Espero vuestra ayuda. Muchas gracias por adelantado.

Comment: Lo primero a hacer es mirar en el JavaDoc la lista de métodos de la clase en cuestión: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Arraylists {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //Array nommal y array de arrays normales
        ArrayList<String> idiomas = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> arrayIdiomas = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

        //Puedes cambiar el valor de 50 por uno mas grande
        for(int i = 0; i < 50; i++){

            if(i < 25) idiomas.add("palabrasEnEspañol");
            if(i >= 25) idiomas.add("palabrasEnIngles");
        }

        //Imprime el array normal
        for(String palabra: idiomas){
            System.out.println(palabra);
        }

        //Array auxiliar
        ArrayList<String> aux = new ArrayList<String>();

        for(int j = 0; j < idiomas.size(); j++){

            if(j == 0 || (j % 25 != 0)){    
                aux.add(idiomas.get(j));
                if(j == idiomas.size()-1){
                    arrayIdiomas.add(aux);
                }
            } else{

                arrayIdiomas.add(aux);
                aux = new ArrayList<String>();
                aux.add(idiomas.get(j));
            }
        }

        //Imprime el array de arrays
        for(ArrayList<String> array: arrayIdiomas){
            System.out.println(array);
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias! Era justo lo que buscaba!

Comment: De nada, un saludo!